# In Googlesheets can you use 4 GPS points to create a bounded area to select all GPS Points from a data set that fall within the area?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, geocoding, latitude-longitude

In Googlesheets, I have Column A1:A1000 as an ID tag, B1:B1000 as Lat points, and C1:C1000 with Long points. IS there a formula or script I can run that will read GPS Points entered in D1,E1,F1,G1 respectively and provide which points from the data set fall within that area? Thanks in advance

Im not very familiar with Javascript but I have tried some basic greater than/less than comparisons.  Unfortunately they have not been successful in pulling all the correct IDs

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Have you read this Google resource: [Capture GPS location](https://support.google.com/appsheet/answer/10106789?hl=en)? It relies on AppSheet.

Comment: Please edit your question to include some sample data  as text (no screen shots please) as well as an example of a successful outcome. You can create a markdown table on line at [www.tablesgenerator.com](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables)